# What is the advantage of Vue in Laravel, Why Laravel not took Angular JS?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

I am a Laravel developer for the last 3 years. I saw many articles in related to Vue and Angular.

Actually I want to know Why Laravel not took Angular JS ?. I think Angular Js more efficient than Vue Js.

Now the final 5.4 version Vue is becoming more popular. so What is the advantage of Blade Template ?

I request all of you to please clarify my points.

Comment: Whatever you think, that's only a framework-creator default. 
You can take any other front-end framework, so question is not relevant.

Comment: Laravel is sponsor of vue.js - If you want the exact reasons for why they chose vue, you'll have to ask the author. But in general vue is way more lightweight than angular. Nobody forces you to decide between blade templates and vue components. You can mix the stuff if you want to. You can use vue for very specific parts of your application. Angular seems to be more of an "allrounder" concept which is hard to mix with the existing functionalities (e.g. Blade templates).

Comment: You can take a look at how Vue compares itself to Angular2 there: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html#Angular-2 Those are good reasons (though debatable of course) to choose Vue over NG.